# programatically pair BLE and send raw data

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’m looking for a simple way to programmatically pair my computer to a remote Bluetooth Low Energy device in such a way that after pairing, I can take control of the BLE socket and have the capability to send/receive raw bytes from the socket. I would like to support as many pairing methods as possible, including Secure Connections. So far, I’ve been able to use BlueZ’s D-Bus API to implement the pairing, but after the pairing process completes I would like to have access to the raw socket to control what gets sent, which appears to be unavailable through BlueZ’s D-Bus api. Currently I am opening a socket using Python’s socket library, but there are certain problems that come with this (i.e. inability to retrieve the ACL connection handle for the connection I paired using BlueZ). I was wondering if there was a better approach that could allow me to get access to the socket and have all the necessary connection information I need to send packets, while still being able to handle the pairing process in a simple manner? Perhaps there is a way to work with BlueZ directly, rather than through the D-Bus API, in order to accomplish this?

I am currently developing on an Ubuntu system in python, but open to other operating systems and programming languages.

Comment: As far as I know over Ble you do not have support for sockets.. however, this does not mean you cant send data over ble.. but the data sent at a time will be very small in quantity...

Comment: Can you elaborate? If I cant send through a socket how can I send? I'm looking for ways to send 'raw' packets, meaning I create the entire packet, including the header. right now the only things I can find don't allow me to control the packet

Comment: What sort of raw data you want to send? What will be the size of your packet?